# Constructing a string with a value from a ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I want to fill a datagridview when an item is selected from a listbox.

My code gives me this error:

> Operator '&' is not defined for string "SELECT DeptName FROM  Department" and type 'DataRowView'.

This my code:

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT DeptName FROM  Departments inner  JOIN Faculties ON Faculties.ID = Departments.FacID where FacID='" & ListBox1.SelectedValue & "'", conn)
    Dim daa As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dtt As New DataTable
    daa.Fill(dtt)
    dgv.DataSource = dtt
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to look at this.

**You could set the `ValueMember` on `ListBox1` beforehand.** Here is an example where the `ListBox` has values from 1 to 10, and their squares. The `ValueMember` is FacID, which is just the number. The `DisplayMember` is the square of FacID (for demonstration purposes!), demonstrating that you don't need to display the value member.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim column1 As New DataColumn("FacID")
    Dim column2 As New DataColumn("Square")
    table.Columns.Add(column1)
    table.Columns.Add(column2)
    For i = 0 To 9
        Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
        row("FacID") = i
        row("Square") = i ^ 2
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next i
    Dim view As New DataView(table)
    ListBox1.DataSource = view
    ' set the DisplayMember and ValueMember
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Square"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "FacID"
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Click
    Dim message = "Selected value: " & ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub
```

This is what the ListBox would look like at run-time

[image]

And when it is clicked, the message showing the selected value

[image]

If this is done before running the code you provided, then you could almost use your code as is, because now `ListBox1.ValueMember` is an integer. Note, you should be more strict and convert the integer to a string in preparation for the query.

```
Dim query =
    "SELECT DeptName FROM Departments " &
    "inner JOIN Faculties ON Faculties.ID = Departments.FacID " &
    "where FacID = '" & ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() & "'"
```

**You could also *not* set the `ValueMember`**. When `ValueMember` is not specified, your `SelectedValue` defaults to the type in the `DataSource`, which is a `DataView`, and, for all intents and purposes, an `IList` of [DataRowView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx).

With no DisplayMember, the ListBox looks like this

[image]

I assume it's not like this. So just set the `ValueMember` beforehand and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox1.SelectedValue` is a `DataRowView`, so you can't add it to a string. you'll probably want something like:

```vb
"SELECT DeptName FROM  Departments inner  JOIN Faculties ON Faculties.ID = Departments.FacID where FacID='" _
     & ListBox1.SelectedValue["yourColumn"].ToString() & "'"
```

Or

```vb
"SELECT DeptName FROM  Departments inner  JOIN Faculties ON Faculties.ID = Departments.FacID where FacID='" _
     & ListBox1.SelectedValue[columnIndex].ToString() & "'"
```